# How to add a data to table on submit

Tags: javascript, html, css

After adding data in form and on click to submit to make this data appear below my table. Like description (that i added) under the description (table) , date (that i added) under the date (table) and so on. And amount under the names should be total amount divided by 4. for example: amount before submit was 100 euro and after submit 25. So eventually everybody will have 25 euro debt. Thanks in advance for any help.
My code is:

```css
#body {
 background-color: grey
}
h1 {
 color:red;
}


.form{
    background:#f1f1f1; 
    width:400px; 
    margin-top:30px; 
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-top:20px; 
    border-radius: 15px;
 }
 .form fieldset{border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
 .form p.contact { font-size: 12px; margin:0px 0px 15px 0;line-height: 10px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica;}
 .form input[type="text"] { width: 350px; }
 .form label { color: #000; font-weight:bold;font-size: 15px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica; }
 
 .form input, textarea { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); 
  border: 1px solid rgba(118, 128, 137, 0.7); 
  padding: 7px; font-family: Keffeesatz, Arial; 
  color: #4b4b4b; 
  font-size: 14px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  margin-bottom: 15px; 
  margin-top: -10px; }
 .form input:focus, textarea:focus { 
  border: 1px solid green; 
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); 
 }
 .form .select-style {
   -webkit-appearance: button;
   -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
   -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   background-image: url(images/select-arrow.png),
     -webkit-linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #F4F4F4 40%, #E5E5E5);
   background-position: center right;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border: 0px solid #FFF;
   color: #555;
   font-size: inherit;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-top: 2px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;}
 
 .form input.buttom{ 
  background: #d8ba23; 
  display: inline-block; 
  padding: 5px 10px 6px; 
  color: black; text-decoration: none; 
  font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #999; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #999; 
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #999; 
  border: none; 
  position: relative; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  font-size: 14px; 
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 }
 .form input.buttom:hover { background-color: #d88323;-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 3px #999; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 3px #999; 
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px #999; }
```

```html
<center>
<div  class="form">

     <form id="contactform" method="post" action="">
    
    <p class="contact"><label for="description">DESCRIPTION</label></p>
    <input id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter the description" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter the description ')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"  type="text">

    <p class="contact"><label for="amount">AMOUNT</label></p>
    <input id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="&#8364" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter the amount ')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" /   type="number">
   
    <p class="contact"><label for="reference period">REFERENCE PERIOD</label></p>
    <input id="reference period" name="reference period" placeholder="Enter the reference period" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter the reference period ')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"  type="text">
<br>
   
            <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="btn" value="SUBMIT" type="submit" \>   
   </form>
 </div></center>
<br>
 

 <div>
  <table>
      <tr><th>SULEYMAN</th></tr>
      <tr><td>DESCRIPTION </td><td>REFERENCE PERIOD </td><td>AMOUNT</td></tr>

      <tr><th>JACOPO</th></tr>
      <tr><td>DESCRIPTION </td><td>REFERENCE PERIOD </td><td>AMOUNT</td></tr>

      <tr><th>DENIS</th></tr>
      <tr><td>DESCRIPTION </td><td>REFERENCE PERIOD </td><td>AMOUNT</td></tr>

      <tr><th>LUCA</th></tr>
      <tr><td>DESCRIPTION </td><td>REFERENCE PERIOD </td><td>AMOUNT</td></tr>
        
     </table>
   
 </div>
```

Comment: Your input names are messed up, you can't have the same name for multiple inputs of the same form.

Comment: ok, i fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you want but have a look and let me know. Also, I don't have the form validations and styling please make sure to include them.
Thanks

```js
  $('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var desc = $('#name').val();
    var amount = $('#username').val();
    var ref = $('#date7').val();
    var amount_byfour = amount/4;
    var desc_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("d");
    for (var i=0; i<desc_elements.length; i++) {
      desc_elements[i].innerHTML+=desc+"<br>";}
    var ref_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("r");
    for (var i = 0; i < ref_elements.length; i++) {
      ref_elements[i].innerHTML+=ref+"<br>";}
    var amount_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < amount_elements.length; i++) {
      amount_elements[i].innerHTML+=amount_byfour+"<br>";}
    var debt_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("debt");
    for (var i=0;i < debt_elements.length; i++){
    var debt = debt_elements[i].innerHTML;
    var debt = Math.round((debt) * 1e12) / 1e12;
    debt_elements[i].innerHTML = debt + amount_byfour;}
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<form id="myForm">
    <p class="contact"><label for="name">DESCRIPTION</label></p>
        <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter the description" required type="text">

        <p class="contact"><label for="username">AMOUNT</label></p>
        <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="&#8364" required type="number">
       
        <p class="contact"><label for="name">REFERENCE PERIOD</label></p>
        <input id="date7" name="name1" placeholder="Enter the reference period" required type="text">

        <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="btn" value="SUBMIT" type="submit">
</form>
</div>
<div>
  <table>
        <tr><th>SULEYMAN</th></tr>
        <tr><td>DESCRIPTION </td><td>REFERENCE PERIOD </td><td>AMOUNT</td><td>DEBT</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="d"></td><td class="r"></td><td class="a"></td><td class="debt">0</td></tr>

        <tr><th>JACOPO</th></tr>
        <tr><td>DESCRIPTION </td><td>REFERENCE PERIOD </td><td>AMOUNT</td><td>DEBT</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="d"></td><td class="r"></td><td class="a"></td><td class="debt">0</td></tr>

        <tr><th>DENIS</th></tr>
        <tr><td>DESCRIPTION </td><td>REFERENCE PERIOD </td><td>AMOUNT</td><td>DEBT</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="d"></td><td class="r"></td><td class="a"></td><td class="debt">0</td></tr>

        <tr><th>LUCA</th></tr>
        <tr><td>DESCRIPTION </td><td>REFERENCE PERIOD </td><td>AMOUNT</td><td>DEBT</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="d"></td><td class="r"></td><td class="a"></td><td class="debt">0</td></tr>
            
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But is it possbile, to make it not delete previous data after i add new one?

Comment: Yes, you can append to the parent. I will edit the answer in few minutes.

Comment: @Highdef has given the answer. Thanks

Comment: @McCormick No problem

Comment: @Highdef Guys i'm sorry for bothering you again. I added new td with name "debt" after "amount" with class c and i want to make it show me total amount of every amount that i submit , in the debt section. And to create checkbox in the amount section. And reduce total debt when user click "checked"  and return it when user "uncheck" it in the amount section. I know that i'm asking too much but i will really appreciate it if you will manage to do this. But in any case thank you so much. You guys help me already a lot.

Comment: @McCormick can you please give more details of what you want with the checkbox, I have added the debt part. Thanks

Comment: In this code I changed: var debt = parseInt(debt);  to:  var debt = Math.round((debt) * 1e12) / 1e12 because it was not counting decimals etc. Like it was giving the sum of 30,75 + 30,75 = 60,75 instead of  61,5.

Comment: @Rohit About checkboxes I want them to adding automatically when I submit an amount. For example I submit an amount and in front of each amount appears the checkbox and when user for example Jacopo has 3 amounts 30, 30, 30 and the debt is 90 when he mark one of the amounts as checked, like he marks 30 as checked the debt reduces to 60 and so on. Sorry for my english. And thanks again)

Comment: @McCormick Sorry! I have been busy. I'll update the answer when I get time. Thanks